# Is there any way to modify variables accessed using closures and have no way to access them

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I just now saw an example of closures in Javascript MDN website. Which is this:

```js
var getCode = (function() {
  var apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2';    // A code we do not want outsiders to be able to modify...
  
  return function() {
    return apiCode;
  };
})();

console.log(getCode());    // Returns the apiCode
```

I'm a beginner and I want to know Is apiCode variable in the code completely unaccessible. Or if there is any way to modify its value

Comment: It's only accessible from within the getCode method.

Comment: There is NO WAY to protect code that is available on the browser. Set a breakpoint and change the variable. TADA. Override the function from the console, set it to whatever you want. Hijack the http request with a proxy, alter it anyway you want.

Comment: @Adriani6 Does it mean that it is unaccessible without changing the code?

Comment: @Hemanbabu Yes. That's the point of a closure. But note what the 2nd comment said. That's fundamentals of client-side development. It all depends on what you mean by accessing the variable. Programatically? Then you're good, anything else you're not good.

Comment: It is protected in a sense that noone can modify it, but everyone can see it, that is for sure.